# DOM Event.StopPropagation to child has no effect

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, event-bubbling

I'm doing a tutorial about Events and I'm stuck with `Event.StopPropagation()` method. It seems that with my example that the bubbling effect to the children are being affected.

Definition of `StopPropagation`:

> The stopPropagation() method prevents propagation of the same event from being called.
> Propagation means bubbling up to parent elements or capturing down to child elements.

At first I thought it was a browser problem but it was not the case. I can't find a solution about this.

Code:

```js
// Event Bubbling and Propagation
//  element.addEventListener( type, func, useCapture);

let m = document.getElementById('m');
let d = document.getElementById('d');
let p = document.getElementById('p');
let s = document.getElementById('s');   

let highlight = (ev)=>{
    //add CSS class "gold" to the clicked element
    ev.stopPropagation();
    let target = ev.currentTarget;
    target.className = 'gold';
    reset(target);
}

let reset = (_element)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        _element.className = '';
    }, 2000);
}

d.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
    ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
    log('Hi I\'m a DIV');
});

[m,d,p,s].forEach((element)=>{
    element.addEventListener('click', highlight);
})
```

```css
#m,#d,#p,#s{    
 border: 2px solid black; 
 padding: 15px;
 margin: 10px;
}
.gold{
    background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<main id="m"> m
        <div id="d"> d
            <p id="p"> p
                <span id="s"> s</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with events, you are overthinking this.

You example is simply applying background color to top element, and as children do not have it defined, its applying the top one below it.

And  if you remove `stopImmediatePropagation()` color will be applied as definition is:  *execute the first event handler, and stop the rest of the event handlers from being executed*, and the first one was simply  `log()`.

In example below, if you apply background color to child elements, you will see they will stay the same. The color it self is applied only on clicked one.

That means the JS event itself did not bubble up to parent elements or capture down. And class was added only on clicked one. Check it with dev tools or add DOM change event listener on every element.

You confused CSS styling with JS event bubbling.

Example:

```js
// Event Bubbling and Propagation
//  element.addEventListener( type, func, useCapture);

let m = document.getElementById('m');
let d = document.getElementById('d');
let p = document.getElementById('p');
let s = document.getElementById('s');
let log = console.log;

let highlight = (ev)=>{
    //add CSS class "gold" to the clicked element
    ev.stopPropagation();
    let target = ev.currentTarget;
    target.className = 'gold';
    reset(target);
}

let reset = (_element)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        _element.className = '';
    }, 2000);
}

d.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
    //ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
    log('Hi I\'m a DIV');
});

[m,d,p,s].forEach((element)=>{
    element.addEventListener('click', highlight);
})
```

```css
#m,#d,#p,#s{    
 border: 2px solid black; 
 padding: 15px;
 margin: 10px;
}

#d {
background-color: blue;
}

#s {
background-color: red;
}

.gold{
    background-color: gold !important;
}
```

```html
<main id="m"> m
        <div id="d"> d
            <p id="p"> p
                <span id="s"> s</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </main>
```

EDIT:

In your example child nodes do not have background property (`rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`), that means you need to set it on click, so that background color of clicked element wont apply on its children.

In code below, you can read the CSS background value of parent element of clicked one, and read its background property. That you take that and apply on all children of clicked one.

This will work in your example.
You can also make sure to apply white to elements if parent was transparent.

Here is a fiddle to play with:
but make sure you will un-comment m (parent) background color to see side effects. You would need to adjust this to suit your production needs

```
const style = getComputedStyle(target.parentNode);
const backgroundColor = style.backgroundColor;

console.clear();
console.log(backgroundColor);


[...target.children].forEach(el => {
if (backgroundColor==="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") {
  el.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }else{
  el.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;}
})
```

```js
// Event Bubbling and Propagation
//  element.addEventListener( type, func, useCapture);

let m = document.getElementById('m');
let d = document.getElementById('d');
let p = document.getElementById('p');
let s = document.getElementById('s');
let log = console.log;

let highlight = (ev)=>{
    //add CSS class "gold" to the clicked element
    ev.stopPropagation();
    let target = ev.currentTarget;
    target.className = 'gold';
    
    const style = getComputedStyle(target.parentNode);
    const backgroundColor = style.backgroundColor;
    
    console.clear();
    console.log(backgroundColor);
    
    
    [...target.children].forEach(el => {
    if (backgroundColor==="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") {
      el.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }else{
      el.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;}
    })

    reset(target);
}

let reset = (_element)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        _element.className = '';
    }, 2000);
}


[m,d,p,s].forEach((element)=>{
    element.addEventListener('click', highlight);
})
```

```css
#m,#d,#p,#s{    
 border: 2px solid black; 
 padding: 15px;
 margin: 10px;
}


#m {
background-color: blue;
}


.gold{
    background-color: gold !important;
}
```

```html
<main id="m"> m
        <div id="d"> d
            <p id="p"> p
                <span id="s"> s</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: But is there a way to control the background color effecting it own element only? 
So that every time a click a element, it will only be the trigger element that will change.

Comment: @johhny I edit my answer, but short answer is there is no easy way. You need to set background color of clicked element children.